# Scripts for Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I couldn't find the scripts for Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS. The only place is [http://stat.bell-labs.com](http://stat.bell-labs.com/project/nlme/MEMSS/index.html#OnLine) which has code for first two chapters. I'd highly appreciate if someone point out the place to get the scripts for this book. Thanks in advance for your time and cooperation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
> library(nlme)
> system.file("scripts", package = "nlme")
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.14/Resources/library/nlme/scripts"
> list.files(system.file("scripts", package = "nlme"))
[1] "ch01.R"   "ch02.R"   "ch03.R"   "ch04.R"   "ch05.R"   "ch06.R"   "ch08.R"  
[8] "sims.rda"
> file.show(system.file("scripts", "ch01.R", package = "nlme"))
```

Magic!

Answer (score 2):

They're in the package itself, in the `inst/scripts` directory.  I'm sure it's possible to get at it from an existing installation but I'm not sure how; I downloaded the source package and looked inside.